# How to execute code after return Result in java Play! Framework?

Tags: java, streaming, playframework-2.2, resource-cleanup

I am using Play! Framework  2.2.1 and I want to stream a file created on the go. After the file is completely streamed I want to clean it up but I have not got any context to do so.

Is there any annotation or callback available for this kind of operation?

Comment: I've end up trying to clean resources call by call and generating new files. It could create unwanted resources stay forever if the file descriptors are blocked I think.

Answer (score 2):

You can copy file content to the FileInputStream, delete the file and then return the stream, anyway, you need to set some headers basing on original file i.e. if you produce ZIPs it can be (*pseudo code!*):

```
public static Result file() {

    File tmpFile = new File("/path/to/your/generated.zip");

    FileInputStream fin = null;
    try {
        fin = new FileInputStream(tmpFile);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    response().setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + tmpFile.getName());
    response().setHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, "application/zip");
    response().setHeader(CONTENT_LENGTH, tmpFile.length() + "");

    tmpFile.delete();

    return ok(fin);
}
```

Other option is writing temporary files to dedicated folder and returning them with common `ok(file);` so you don't need to care about creation of headers, anyway you need to  write scheduler task which will delete files older than *n* minutes/hours every *x* minutes.

Comment: I'll try the first code. Second options is not safe because if the file is too big and the bandwidth is short it could end up in an exception isn't it? Of course I could catch it.

Comment: You can't however tmpFile is deleted _before_ the return

Comment: This code is wrong because it breaks the file download, it cuts it. Thanks anyway. I've solved it by cleaning up resources each time the request is received.